# How to call an external window-app in Scala (or Java) and WAIT for it to be closed?

Tags: java, macos

I use macOS and, from Scala, I like to call the default text editor on text files. I want the user to be able to edit/modify the file, and be called back / notified in any form when this editing is finished, thus the editor quit.
Alternatively, a notification on any modification after saving (in particular the first) would do the job. Ideally there would be a notification when the external process is actually finished since the text file is only created temporarily by my app.

Comment: This is complex as the editor is not under control of the calling code so you need notifications etc. It would be much easier to use a java editor./text widget  that you can call and control